# What is the best material for building an web application firewall?

Tags: web-application, firewalls, waf

I am a newbie in this field, and want to study more about Web Application Firewall. Could anyone tell me any materials or tutorials that I can refer in order to write (build) a Web Application Firewall from scratch?

I am planning to build a WAF which can prevent already-known maliciousnesses such as: SQL injection, XSS ATTACK, ect... at the same time, can study normal users over a period of time, and later prevent anomolies base on the learned data.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the existing products, to see what they do, and how they work? Look at open source projects, as they're more accessible than commercial products.

Comment: why re-invent the wheel? why not support or upgrade previously developed very stable and powerful wafs? like mod-security, Lua resty?

Comment: This is just as broad as asking how to build a web application.

Comment: So sorry for a broad question, I tried to edit it to make it narrower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's depends on your purpose of the firewall, honestly, some web application firewalls mostly offer a different solution each other.

From my own experience, I created a so called web application firewall by utilizing nginx reverse proxy to receive request first on a server, then filter them to my backend server where the real stuff located.

[Nginx has a great documentation about it](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/), you can start from it.

Then you can add your own features from your reverse proxy server. You can add a bunch of iptables rules if you prefer it, especially to [provide a basic DDoS protection](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-configure-iptables-to-block-common-dos-attacks).

You can add mod_security also for a more advanced protection features. [This guide](https://geekflare.com/install-modsecurity-on-nginx/) can help you to explore it, [and also some OWASP rules](https://geekflare.com/modsecurity-owasp-core-rule-set-nginx/) because (maybe) it's a common standard for people who build their firewall using mod_security.

Again, your web application firewall's feature is your own choice. It's a large field to explore, start from "hardened reverse proxy server" (cool name, eh?), you can continue to another type such as DNS based firewall, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what are you looking for and your scope.

As a newbie, you can try already existing ones as:

- OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set (CRS)
- Baracuda
- AQTRONIX WebKnight
- IronBee

or whatever you like.

Here you can find some suggestions:
http://linuxbsdos.com/2011/12/06/3-application-level-firewalls-for-linux-distributions/